# How do you view the docker build cache for buildkit builds?

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

I've gotten an image building using the new `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` builder, specifically to use `--mount=cache`. After building my image a couple times I noticed the cache usage is already past 3Gb, I'd like to see the size of the objects in the cache to figure out if it's because I'm caching too many things or if there are just multiple versions being stored. However, the docker cli doesn't have any mechanism for exploring the cache afaict.

Answer (score 1):

```
Like other cache types, local cache gets replaced on export, by replacing the contents of the index.json file. However, previous caches will still be available in the blobs directory. These old caches are addressable by digest, and kept indefinitely. Therefore, the size of the local cache will continue to grow (see moby/buildkit#1896 for more information).
```

https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/backends/local/#cache-versioning

If however you really want to inspect the actual cache, you can use the `--cache-to` option where you can specify a directory and then you can look around like in any other folder.